# Localização do arquivo txt Android ndk / C++

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

Fiz um código c++ para criar um arquivo:
[image: Arquivo com C++]

Ja dei permissão no manifest para ler e gravar:

[image: Permissão no manifest]
Minha duvida é:Onde que ele salva esse arquivo no celular???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra quem tiver o mesmo problema: o unico jeito que encontrei de localizar os arquivos gerados foi com um aplicativo de terceiros como o ES File Explorer.
Pelo PC ele não mostra os arquivos.
Ao salvar os arquivos fiz o seguinte:

```
myfile.open("/storage/emulate/0/suaPasta");
```

Achei que por estar gravando usando android NDK ele salvaria em um local diferente.

Para ver os arquivos pelo PC tem que mover pelo ES File Explorer para uma pasta que tenha acesso pelo PC como a pasta da camera ou a pasta de Downloads ou para o cartão de memória.